# NUC11 will not boot from USD - trying to run RAM health check

Tags: boot, usb, kernel

I've just installed Server 20.0.4 LTS on my brand new NUC11TNHi7 (barebones) but things are not well. Yesterday I was constantly getting Kernel Panic restarts. Today I'm trying to flash MemTest86 to make sure my RAM has not been damaged or incompatible (as I read some have experienced this) I have disabled safe boot which should allow me to boot from USD. I have set USD as priority in my setup (F2) but nothing. On F10 interrupt, I'm unable to select my flash drive - it shows both my SSD and Flashdrive, but will not allow me to select "UEFI:JetFlashTranscend 4GB 8.07". The drive is a few years old - not sure if that could have an effect. Lexar SODIMM 3200 32GB x 2 and Crucial 2TB SSD NVME

Comment: My kernel panic restart loop started again halfway through installing my application (was doing a required update while installing)

Comment: My kernel panic restart loop started again halfway through installing my application (was doing a required update while installing) Here's the exact moment it goes into the kernel panic: Scanning Btrfs filesystems. Done.  Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.34 [/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/nvmeOn1p2] fsch.ext4 -a -CO /dev/nvmeOn1p2/dev/nvmeOn1p2: recovering journal.  Next line is the start of the Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler

Comment: What is "USD"? Is it US dollar?